# unable to start Anaconda in Windows

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda

I am unable to start anaconda environment after installing some updates following is the error that I get in command prompt

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]
(c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\MOHIT>conda
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MOHIT\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py", line 3, in <module>
    import conda.cli
  File "C:\Users\MOHIT\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .main import main  # NOQA
  File "C:\Users\MOHIT\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 40, in <module>
    import importlib
  File "C:\Users\MOHIT\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    import types
  File "C:\Users\MOHIT\Anaconda3\lib\types.py", line 166, in <module>
    import functools as _functools
  File "C:\Users\MOHIT\Anaconda3\lib\functools.py", line 23, in <module>
    from weakref import WeakKeyDictionary
  File "C:\Users\MOHIT\Anaconda3\lib\weakref.py", line 12, in <module>
    from _weakref import (
ImportError: cannot import name '_remove_dead_weakref'

C:\Users\MOHIT>
```

Please help.

Comment: tried in cmd as admin getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

When installing conda make sure to UNCHECK "Register Anaconda as the system Python x.x" as shown in the [MinicondaInstaller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hE3hB.png). 
Otherwise everything becomes meaningless and you wonder why is this happening to you and you cry a little.

I don't know why this solved the problem for me, but I think it has something to do with keeping your system python and your virtual env python separate. Took me a whole day of work just to debug it.